# How is it possible to convert mouse vertical/horizonta position to width (px) JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement, mousemove

Having the dynamically changed mouse position I'm trying to convert it to width pixels, making it  0px if the mouse is at the bottom of the screen and 100px if the mouse is at the top frame of the screen, how is it possible in js? Probably I would need a regular converting expression. Maybe I also would need an if statement?

```js
let posY = 0.23       // received from the outer function
const el = document.querySelector(".el")

el.style.width = (posY*2 ...) + 'px',  //trying to write this line, make it wider if posY > 0, more narrow if posY < 0 relatively
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal runable example where you have the HTML (class `el`?), and the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it would be something like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const MAX_WIDTH = 100;
  const viewportHeight = (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight);
  const elBar = document.querySelector('.bar');
  const elInfo = document.querySelector('.info');

  window.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
    const width = parseInt(((viewportHeight - event.offsetY) / viewportHeight) * MAX_WIDTH);
    elBar.style.width = `${width}px`;
    elInfo.innerHTML = `Width: ${width}px`;
  });
});
```

```css
.bar {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="info">Try to move your mouse here</div>
```

Try to move around your mouse above the snippet, up and down. It should show you the translated size in pixel according to the mouse position on the viewport.

Comment: The `viewportHeight` is a variable to store the browser's height. There is also `event.offsetY` that provides information in pixel about mouse vertical position within the browser, which is 0 for the very top of the browser and the value is going higher for the bottom. Since the question was about having it "inverted" (higher value for top and lower for bottom), then the calculation should be about calculating the opposite. Later, this calculation result is being used as the "percentage" to the `MAX_WIDTH` value.